# What`s the compression ratio of NSData from AVCaptureStillImageOutput?

Tags: ios

Use `jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation`: method can get `NSData` from `AVCapureStillImageOutput`, then I can write the data to a file.

```
NSData * imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
```

Just `imageSampleBuffer` turn to `NSData`. Can I get the compression radio in this method, or is there some index to measure for this?

Just like `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage* image, 1.0)` this, it has 1.0 to measure the compression radio for image.

Comment: I think the docs tell you: [`Discussion:
This method merges the image data and Exif metadata sample buffer attachments **without re-compressing the image**.`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureStillImageOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/AVCaptureStillImageOutput/jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:) So if you did not compress the image I'd assume it is 1.0.

Comment: I agree that ,but not a good answer.Just a Assumption.Or may be when I  use jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation: method can get NSData from AVCapureStillImageOutput ,it has compress already. I just do a assumption for that.

Answer (score 3):

You can control the compression (0-1) that is used by the AVCaptureStillImageOutput.

```
[stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:@{AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoQualityKey:@1.0}];
```

See AVCaptureOutput.h and AVVideoSettings.h:
AVVideoQualityKey is supported on iOS 6.0 and later and may only be used when AVVideoCodecKey is set to AVVideoCodecJPEG. AVVideoQualityKey NSNumber (0.0-1.0, JPEG only)

You can quickly verify that this key works by looking at the size of the data for different values. As for the default value I don't think it's 1.0 because when I set it to 1.0 the size bumps up a bit and I didn't setup a tripod to attempt to take exactly the same pic....